# eXist-db - redeploying library package using autodeploy mechanism or alternative

Tags: exist-db

I have created my own application of type library using the exist eXide interface. Using exide ui have downloaded the application package (the xar file).

To deploy the package on our build server via docker file , I am  using the autodeploy mechanism:

I copy my library application package xar (zip) file  to the 
`/exist/autodeploy` folder just before entry-point command (e.g before starting up existdb jetty).

All works fine , library gets deployed.

However that works only once. Any other deployment of newer version of library using the auto deploy mechanism ends up with message being logged in the `expath-repo.log` file :

```
Application package "my library name"  already installed. Skipping.
```

I have tried to put uninstall commands (using `repo:undeploy, repo:unistall`) to the `pre-install.xql`  script, but although the script uninstalls the library when executed from exide editor, during the auto deploy does not seems to be triggered.

Is there any option how to force the auto-deploy to redeploy the package instead of skipping its installation ?

If not, what would be the direction I should take to automate the process of redeploying the library ?

Thank you very much for any insight.

Comment: Which package are you using? If it is a custom package, how have you defined the version of the package - can you show some examples?

Comment: Hello adamretter.  I edited my question to be more clear. The xar package is being generated from the exide ui "Download app" menu. I do not do any modification to it. The problem that I am facing is that it looks like that the auto deploy feature can only support installation and not re-installation.  I have also tried to bump the version of the app (from exide ui -> edit Descriptors) but with no success. The package with higher version is detected by the auto-deploy but still ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code which generates the log message you see:

```
if (packages != null
            && (!enforceDeps || pkgVersion.equals(packages.latest().getVersion()))) {
    LOG.info("Application package " + name + " already installed. Skipping.");
    final Package pkg = packages.latest();
    return Optional.of(getTargetCollection(broker, pkg, getPackageDir(pkg)));
}
```

It would seem that you would only get this under two circumstances:

1. Your package has dependencies on other packages that are not yet installed.
2. Your package does not have a newer version number than a package of the same name which is already installed.

Comment: I have checked the code of the `org.exist.repo.Deployment` class. I  tried to modify the version attribute of the package element in the descriptor `expath-pkg.xml`. When providing the xar file with  version bumped up via the auto deploy mechanism, the package is still skipped. Unfortunately the method does not provide more logging information.  My resolution is that when using autodeploy, the bumping of the version has no effect. My library has no dependencies. I will try to describe the problem on your github page so you can reproduce it and confirm or reject. Thank you anyway for helping !